# mysql database PHP table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I currently have a database on mysql with some products and I am printing them in a table, as you can see here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP3r5.png?6513]

Well thats fine for now but... I want to set certain images to the products name.
For example, I would go on top of the name "Jeans Fit" (hover in css) and it would appear the products image. How can I set certain images to the products names? Not randomly, I want to choose each one, if you could guide me on this one ...

Here is my code to print the table:

```
<?php

// to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";

if($action=='add'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " foi adicionado ao carrinho</div>";
}

if($action=='exists'){
    echo "<div>" . $name . " já existe no carrinho</div>";
}

require "libs/DbConnect.php";


// page is the current page, if there's nothing set, default is page 1
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

// set records or rows of data per page
$recordsPerPage = 6;

// calculate for the query LIMIT clause
$fromRecordNum = ($recordsPerPage * $page) - $recordsPerPage;
// select all data
$query = "SELECT 
            id, name,price 
        FROM 
            products
        ORDER BY 
            id 
        LIMIT 
            {$fromRecordNum}, {$recordsPerPage}";

            /*
            page and its LIMIT clause looks like:
            1 = 0, 5
            2 = 5,10
            3 = 10,15
            4 = 15, 20
            5 = 20, 25
            */

$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

//this is how to get number of rows returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();


if($num>0){
    echo "<table border='0'>";//start table

        // our table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAligncenter'>Nome Produto</th>";
            echo "<th>Preço (EUR)</th>";
            echo "<th>Acção</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignRight'>{$price}</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignCenter'>";
                    echo "<a href='addToCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='customButton'>";
                        echo "<img src='images/add-to-cart.png'  class='imagem2'title='Adicionar ao carrinho' />";
                    echo "</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";
}

// no products in the database
else{
    echo "No products found.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Change:

From:

```
<a href='addToCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='customButton'>
```

to:

```
<a href='addToCart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' onmouseover="document.images['image'].src='images/your_image.jpg' class='customButton'>
```

Comment: but that only will give me one of the products working, right?? :s

Comment: I think so, well, check this link, i think it could help: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/

Comment: do you understand about php? im really getting mad at that "problem" xD and also my php it's not that great.

Comment: well that link isn't what it works for my code i think bro.
is it possible to , add like images according to my products id?.
set image X to product with id 5 and what so ever.
that would work? i have the logic but making that into code is hard for me in php :s